# ¿Cómo conectar mi http.server en Python sin poner en :8000 al final de mi IP?

Tags: python, web, servidor, router, puertos

Desde Linux con la Raspberry ponía:

```
sudo python -m SimpleHTTPServer 80
```

y podía entrar desde el navegador poniendo 192.168.1.85

Pero desde Windows con Python3 se hace diferente:

```
python3 -m http.server
```

Pero me veo en la obligación de poner en el navegador:

```
 192.168.1.26:8000
```

¿Qué solución hay para evitar poner el `:8000` al final de la IP?

Aparte, desde Raspbian podía igualmente poniendo mi IP pública 90.xx.xx.xx y abriendo los puertos en el router, pero con el p`ython3 -m http.server` no puedo acceder de esa forma igualmente abriéndole sus puertos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

puedes hacerlo asi:

```
python -m http.server 80
```

el puerto por default para conexiones http es `80`

**referencia:**
[http.server](https://docs.python.org/3/library/http.server.html#http-server-cli)

Comment: puedes mejorar la respuesta, explica que debe definir el puerto por defecto y ejecutar el comando, agrega documentacion

Comment: Si quieres acceder desde tu ip publica debe hacer un port forwarding en tu router y eso es de redes.